Extract values from arrays in
I have a response object that I'm wanting to extract all of the id values out, but I'm not sure the best way to go about it...
const obj = {
  "responseArray":[
    {
      "accounts":[
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"123",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"456",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "accounts":[
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"987",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"654",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The closest I've gotten is with mapping
const mapped = obj.responseArray.map(item => item?.accounts.map(acc => acc.products.map(prod => prod.id)))

// Response
// [ [ [Array], [Array] ], [ [Array], [Array] ] ]

These Array bits do actually contain the IDs I'm after, it's just obviously not in the format I'd like...

If you don‘t know the depth or if the depth could change you will most likely need a recursive function.

This question is similar to: How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What's your intended use of the output? If you just want an array of the ids, then you can use reduce() or flatMap(). If you want to perform an action based on other properties within each product, then use a looping mechanism - any will do.

@RoryMcCrossan indeed I was just wanting an array of the IDs. I considered reduce but I've not used it enough to be confident doing it. I ended up using the flatMap as suggested below.

You can use flatMap to get a simple array instead of an array of arrays :


const obj = {
  "responseArray":[
    {
      "accounts":[
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"123",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"456",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "accounts":[
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"987",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "products":[
            {
              "id":"654",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const mapped = obj.responseArray.flatMap(item => item?.accounts.flatMap(acc => acc.products.map(prod => prod.id)))

console.log(mapped)




Genius! I wondered if something like this would exist haha

With "modern" (Chrome 69, Firefox 62, Edge 79, Opera 56, Safari 12) versions of JavaScript you can Array.prototype.flatMap:
obj.responseArray
  .flatMap(x => x.accounts)
  .flatMap(x => x.products)
  .map(x => x.id)
// [ '123', '456', '987', '654' ]

flatMap takes a function that returns an array and will map all arrays of this function into one big array, which can then be further processed.

I am using the forEach to get the job done.


const obj = {
  "responseArray": [{
      "accounts": [{
          "products": [{
            "id": "123",
          }]
        },
        {
          "products": [{
            "id": "456",
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "accounts": [{
          "products": [{
            "id": "987",
          }]
        },
        {
          "products": [{
            "id": "654",
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
let result=[];
obj.responseArray.forEach(o=>{
    o.accounts.forEach(account=>{
    account.products.forEach(product=>{
        result.push(product.id);
    })
  })
})
console.log(result)




I guess what you are looking for is something like this,
We need to use flatMap to flatten and map over the arrays:


obj.responseArray
    .flatMap(item => item.accounts)
    .flatMap(account => account.products)
    .map(product => product.id);

// response: [ '123', '456', '987', '654' ]



